# ')' Expected Error - VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting this `')' expected` error on the Bold character. Can someone help me.

```
Private msngSingle (,) As Single = ((51**,** 0, 0, 0),
    (552, 0, 0.15, 51), 
    (1196, 75.15, 0.28, 552), 
    (2662, 255.47, 0.31, 2662), 
    (5750, 709.93, 0.36, 2662),
    (99999, 1821.61, 0.396, 5750))

Private msngMarried (,) As Single = ((124**,** 0, 0, 0),
    (960, 0, 0.15, 124), 
    (2023, 125.4, 0.28, 960), 
    (3292, 423.04, 0.31, 2023), 
    (5809, 816.43, 0.36, 3292), 
    (99999, 1722.55, 0.396, 5809))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use braces on a literal array rather than parentheses, i.e. {} rather than ().